# Antimatter transmission

Tags: pair-production

Well, i am theorizing a new method energy transmission, and need some advice.
I have DC current being generated, and wanted to think of a unique solution to transfer electricity without any transmission loss. 
So, i thought about E = mc^2, and realized that energy is matter, and then it occured to me that you can't have loss in matter(or antimatter), unless it annihilates. So, i was looking into the most efficient method for creating antimatter ?? I will transfer it using magnetic fields, and use the photovoltaic effect of gamma ray production from annihilation,on lead or a lead based compound.
I want to know the most efficient method of converting electrical energy into antimatter and matter(pair production)(assuming that i have a lot of electricity).
I want to know the strength of magnetic field needed to deflect the positrons created, and if there is any compound of lead which works better then lead at interacting with gamma rays (511 keV each)(there are 2 gamma rays for each positron-electron annihilation)

Comment: better to ask merely _how to convert electricity to anti matter ?_

Comment: It's already possible to transmit electricity without any loss: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity. I suggest you focus your research efforts on room-temperature superconductors. Your antimatter won't travel very far unless it's in a vacuum.

Comment: There are no efficient methods to create antimatter. That's thermodynamically impossible. The cheapest antimatter (positrons) is claimed to cost about 25 billion dollar per gram and if you want anti-hydrogen, it's apparently on the order of 60 trillion dollar per gram. In other words: except for experiments at the atomic level and for specialty applications the stuff is uselessly expensive.